# DataTable search filter, sorting and pagination not working after fetching JSON data using Promise.fetch

Tags: json, promise, datatables, fetch

I have a DataTable that display JSON data from Promise fetch. It uses loops over the JSON data and displays it in the `tbody`. The problem I'm having now is that, all the rows of the JSON data fetched appears in the table with no pagination, and the search filter and column sorting aren't working as well.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tierlist">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Card Image</th>
              <th>Rarity</th>
              <th>Character</th>
              <th>Attribute</th>
              <th>R Factor Scene</th>
              <th>Overall STR</th>
              <th>HP</th>
              <th>SP</th>
              <th>ATK</th>
              <th>DEF</th>
              <th>HIT</th>
              <th>AVO</th>
              <th>LUK</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody id="datarows">
          </tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var table = $('#tierlist').DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      initComplete: function () {
      $('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').css({ 'width': '50px', 'display': 'inline-block' });
      }
   });

    // Data URL
  const URL = "https://somedomain/data.json";

  // Promise fetch the data and display it
  fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((cards) => datarows.innerHTML = displayCards(cards))
    .then(table.clear().draw());

  const displayCards = (cards) => {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<cards.length; i++) {
      out += '<tr><td><img height="35" src="' + cards[i].skill + '" /></td>' +
          '<td><img height="70" src="' + cards[i].cardImage + '" /></td>' +
                '<td>' + cards[i].rarity + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].character + '</td>' + 
                '<td><img height="35" src="' + cards[i].attribute + '" /></td>' +
                '<td>' + cards[i].rFactorScene + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].STR + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].HP + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].SP + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].ATK + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].DEF + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].HIT + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].AVO + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + cards[i].LUK + '</td></tr>' ; 
    }
    return out;
  };
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are adding to the table in HTML is not added to the DataTable object. 
The following jsfiddle solves your issue by instead of adding the fetched data to the HTML table, adding it to the DataTable object and redrawing it.

The important difference is displayed here (addData replaces displayCards):

```js
function addData(cards){
  cards.forEach(card => {
    table.row.add([
      '<img height="35" src="' + card.skill + '" />',
      '<img height="70" src="' + card.cardImage + '" />',
      card.rarity, 
      card.character,
      '<img height="35" src="' + card.attribute + '" />',
      card.rFactorScene,
      card.STR,
      card.HP,
      card.SP,
      card.ATK,
      card.DEF,
      card.HIT,
      card.AVO,
      card.LUK
    ]);
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ja03o65r/30/